# Python webscraping: Image incomplete when using urllib

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve an image using Python and BeautifulSoup. I managed to get the full url of the image but when I use `urllib.urlretrieve(imagelink, filename)`, it retrieves the image but the image is incomplete, only 3.2kb.

The real images (im getting a lot of images) average around 800kb. It iterates through and downloads all the images but none of them are viewable and are all the same filesize. The full image urls work fine when opened in the browser though.

Any idea what could cause such an issue? I don't think showing my code would help but here is the section where I am getting the url:

```
print imagelink
filename = imagelink.split('/')[-1]
time.sleep(5)
urllib.urlretrieve(imagelink, filename)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: As `urlretrieve` may download a cached version (which may be outdated) it could be beneficial to call `urllib.urlcleanup()` between `urlretrieve` calls of the same link. Read through the docs but couldn't see anything obviously wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Oooh I see. I didn't know about `urlcleanup()`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `requests`:

```
import requests
url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkGEv.jpg?s=328&g=1'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('tkGEv.jpg', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Comment: @Bruno requests is easy to use, you can check this url :http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

Comment: Great, I'm gonna read through that documentation now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

宏杰李, requests is a wrapper for urllib. As it is also a wrapper for sockets -))

With urllib2 the same result can be achieved like this.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkGEv.jpg?s=328&g=1')
>>> with open("/home/ziya/Pictures/so_image.jpg", "wb") as img:
...     img.write(r.read())
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I clearly have a lot to learn. I haven't used urllib2 before but I want to check it out now. Thanks